# Twilio statusCallback doesn't fire

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to set up messages delivery status check with twilio. For some reasons twilio statusCallback doesn't fire. Could you please help me to find an error?

Here is a file where I do initialization and send messages:

```
const Twilio = require('twilio');
const {
  TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
  TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN,
  TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER
} = require('config');

const client = new Twilio(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

module.exports = {
  send: (body, phoneNumber) => client.messages.create({
    body,
    to: phoneNumber,
    from: TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
    statusCallback: 'http://postb.in/b/XXXXXXXX'
  })
    .then((message) => {
      console.log(message.sid);

      return message.sid;
    })
};
```

Here is a test where I call message sending after initialization:

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const smsUtility = require('utils/sms');

describe('Sms utility', () => {
  it('should send a message and return message sid', (done) => {
    const body = 'Body';
    const number = '+XXXXXXXXXXX';

    smsUtility.send(body, number)
      .then((messageSid) => {
        expect(typeof messageSid).to.equal('string');

        return done();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);

        return done();
      });
  });
});
```

I use test credentials, but when I replace it with real twilio credentials, I successfully receive a message, so this part works fine. Also, when I try to ping `postb.in` url manually (with curl), it also works OK. Only `statusCallback` doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks to me like you have everything set up nicely aside from your Postbin URL.

I noticed you show your URL as `http://postb.in/b/XXXXXXXX`. But the `/b/` version of the URL is the dashboard for your Postbin. Requests to the dashboard won't show up on the dashboard.

Instead, you should use the URL that looks like: `http://postb.in/XXXXXXXX`. Try that and let me know if it's working.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to remove /b/, but it also doesn't work, Twilio doesn't send request to this url.

Comment: I will come back to this on Monday and test, but I am concerned that something else is up as Twilio is happy to send webhooks to any URL you supply.

Comment: I just tried with your exact code (well, I had to make the `require('config')` a local require and update the postb.in URL) and it worked for me. My Postbin received two callbacks, one for the message being "sent" and one when it was "delivered". I'm not sure what else to suggest. Are you able to try a URL that you are hosting rather than a third party like postb.in?

Comment: Thanks, you're right about /b/ in Postbin URL. The second problem was in my code, now everything works fine.